# xterm doesn't switch directory when it is moved

Tags: shell, directory, rename

Recently I was very frustrated with xterm not behaving as expected. This is what I was doing:

1. open xterm
2. run the following commands:

   ```
   $ mkdir test_01
   $ cd test_01/
   $ echo 'a' > a
   $ cat a
   ```

   The output will be:

   ```
   a
   ```
3. open another xterm (don't close the first one)
4. run the following commands:

   ```
   $ mv test_01/ test_01_old
   $ mkdir test_01
   $ cd test_01
   $ echo 'b' > a
   $ cat a
   ```

   The output will be:

   ```
   b
   ```
5. now in the original xterm run the command:

   ```
   $ cat a
   ```

   The output will be:

   ```
   a
   ```

**Why does this happen?** At this stage, both xterms report the same directory with the `pwd` command (which is `/home/user_1/test_01`).

Comment: This is probably not `xterm`-related.  (An `xterm` can't tell if it is running *a shell* or `nethack` and has no idea what directory the shell it runs considers the `cwd`.)  Btw, while `pwd` might be the same, `ls -ld /proc/self/cwd` of both Xterms probably differs.

Comment: sr_ Thanks for the edits! Looks much nicer) And you are right! It actually is different, the output shows that the directory in reality moved.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has little to do with xterm. You could do the same thing with two shells without invoking xterm at all. For that matter, you could do it with one shell (see below).

Each process has a current working directory. This isn't tracked by name, but as a pointer (more or less) to the directory itself. (I'm not sure how it's represented internally; it may be something like the major and minor device numbers and the inode number for the directory.)

The shell running in your first xterm has `test_01` as its current directory. That directory is then renamed (by another process) from `test_01` to `test_01_old` -- but it's still the same directory, and the shell process still has it as its current directory.

The kernel doesn't remember the name of the current directory, but your shell does. It uses this information when you run the built-in `pwd` command. The shell under your first xterm didn't notice that directory was renamed, so when you type `pwd` it prints the cached path.

But `/bin/pwd` is an external command, and it doesn't have access to the shell's cached information. It works by starting from the current directory (whose name it doesn't immediately know), looking at its `..` entry, and traversing up the directory hierarchy until it gets to the root (i.e., the directory whose `..` entry points to itself); it then prints the path elements in reverse order delimited by `/` characters.

For example, I just did the following on my system (Ubuntu 12.04, bash 4.2.24):

```
$ pwd ; /bin/pwd
/home/kst
/home/kst
$ mkdir test_01
$ cd test_01
$ pwd ; /bin/pwd
/home/kst/test_01
/home/kst/test_01
$ mv /home/kst/test_01 /home/kst/test_01_old
$ pwd ; /bin/pwd
/home/kst/test_01
/home/kst/test_01_old
$ cd $(/bin/pwd)
$ pwd ; /bin/pwd
/home/kst/test_01_old
/home/kst/test_01_old
$
```

As you can see, `pwd` and `/bin/pwd` are consistent *until* I rename the current directory; then the shell's built-in `pwd` prints what it remembers the current directory to be. But when I do `cd $(/bin/pwd)`, the two are in synch again.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that! Also, I forgot that the shell might have built-in replacements for some commands.